# Terraform cloud init template read file

Tags: terraform

I am trying to include content by reading a script file in cloud init template file as below using terraform. I get the below mentioned error. When I include the contents directly without reading from the file it works as expected. Is there a way to include the contents by reading from file.

```
- content: "${file("${path.module}/scripts/restore.sh")}"
  path: /opt/data/restore.sh 
  permissions: '0755'
  owner: admin:admin
```

Error -  failed to render : <template_file>:49,20-24: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "path".

Adding templatefile

```
data "template_file" "script" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/cloud_init.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    prefix = "${var.prefix}"
  }
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = "${data.template_file.script.rendered}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the `templatefile` invocation to the question.